# Valid range for java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date, jvm

what is the range for valid values that I can store in java.util.Date? 
The [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) doesn't say much about this.

Or does it only support dates that can be expressed as unix timestamps (that is dates after 1.1.1970)? If so, is there maybe a (serializeable) class in the JDK that supports also dates prior to that?

What I'm looking for is a class/type for a birthday-field in db4o

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It supports dates between Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE:

```
class DateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy G, HH:mm:ss.S Z");

        System.out.println(df.format(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)));
        System.out.println(df.format(new Date(0)));
        System.out.println(df.format(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE)));
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
2 Dec 292269055 BC, 10:47:04.192 -0600
31 Dec 1969 AD, 18:00:00.0 -0600
17 Aug 292278994 AD, 01:12:55.807 -0600
```

*(Note: times above are Central Time)*

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt - Although `Date` itself doesn't have an era field (at least not an accessible one) - if I were to wrap it in a `Calendar`, it could be printed.

Comment: Guess what Date.toString() does (after guessing what System.println(Object) does).

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt - `Date#toString()` does its own fun little concatenation to build the outputted string, and it doesn't seem to have any case where it would print the era designator. Updated my example to use a `DateFormat`.

Comment: @Rob: Hm, I could swear I've seen a version of Date that delegated all of the date arithmetic to java.util.Calendar, but now it looks like they're both based on some sun.util.* classes.

Comment: @Michael - Just for kicks I looked at the source for 7 (I was looking at 6 earlier), and 7 is also backed by the Sun implementations. Maybe those are wrappers for `java.util.Calendar` in 7? I didn't go that far into the source.

Comment: any ideas why `java.sql.Timestamp` doesn't behave the same way in spite of being based on `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 15):

`java.util.Date` stores dates in a `long` as milliseconds using 1970-01-01 as a reference. Since `long` is a signed 64-bit integer, you can expect `java.util.Date` to cover about 290 million years before and after the reference date - that is if you don't care about accurate representation and calendar system switches.

Unless you are planning a birthday party for a dinosaur, I'd say that java.util.Date is probably fine for your purpose...

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. I didn't know negative values were valid for timestamps.

Comment: java.util.Date covers more than 292 million years BC while dinosaurs first appeared between 247 and 240 million years ago. So planning a birthday party for a dinosaur shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Dates can contain values before 1.1.1970, just use negative long :-)