# from timestamp (long integer) into date format using java

Tags: java, timestamp, long-integer

I am getting error out-of-range when I was trying to convert timestamp into date format.

```
long timeStamp = 1342049220104;
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(timeStamp);
Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
System.out.println(date);
```

The error that I got "The literal 1342049220104 of type int is out of range".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488038/valid-range-for-java-util-date

Answer (score 2):

You have to write it like this, with an `L` character appended:

```
long timeStamp = 1342049220104L;
```

Otherwise your literal number is interpreted as a 32-bit `int` rather than a 64-bit `long`.

See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) to learn more about Java primitive values.

Answer (score 0):

```
long timeStamp = 1342049220104L;
```

See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), you can use:

```
new Date(timeStamp);
```